# SQL successful query code

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-express

Does SQL Server Express return codes when a query is successful? And how can you capture this in C#?

Thank you

I have a next button that allows me the next 10 rows from a table. I want to base this continued button based on if the previous query was successful.

Comment: Show the code and then we can see. Otherwise it's going to be closed

Comment: successful as in 'returns rows' or successful as in 'doesn't throw an error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of note if the query fails you will get an exception so nothing will be returned, unless of course you catch your exception then you can make it return whatever you like!

I think maybe you are thinking of **[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)** which for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` command will return the number of rows affected (by all statements in the command), or return -1 if the transaction was rolled back. It will not return the number of rows affected by select statements, but this shouldn't be an issue because there is no reason to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for `SELECT` statements.

If you simply want a COUNT of results returned you can either use a `COUNT` query in conjunction with **[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)**.

If you are using **[SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)** you can either use the **[HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx)** Property for a boolean value of if it return rows, or while you are using the reader you could use a counter to return the exact number of rows, e.g.:

```
int rowcount = 0;
bool success = false;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        success = reader.HasRows;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rowcount++;
            // DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR DATA
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you are using SqlDataAdapter you can use the count of rows from your **[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)** to get either a boolean value for success or the number of rows affected.

```
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table", "connectionString"))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);

    bool success = table.Rows.Count > 0;
    int rows = table.Rows.Count;

}
```

Comment: Thank you GarethD. i will take your answers and apply them to my code.  i was told Oracle based database return a specific value so i was not sure if  MS SQL Server Express did something Similar.  Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you're generating your query it's hard to tell you exactly how to do this but if you are using an SQLDataReader you could check its HasRows property or if you're using a DataTable you could check against its Rows.Count property.

Comment: I use a Connection, Command, and then an adapter to fill a datatable. i thought the SQL server would return a int value like 100 when a query is commplete or -1 if it is a failure....

Comment: It returns rows if it has rows.  It doesn't if it doesn't.  Why would it need a return code?

Comment: i was told Oracle datbases returns like 100 if the query executes successfully, or -1 if it does not, does SQL express do something similiar?